# Get name of currently executing Azure Function app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am looking for a way to get the name of the Azure FunctionApp currently being executed at runtime.

Is this possible? In C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set value in config during function deployment and get this value at runtime if you need

Comment: The appname or the name of the function that is being executed?

Comment: @PeterBons I need the app name, not the function being executed

Comment: @zolty13, This is a good approach. I have kept it as my last resort. This would require pipeline changes, also it is more error prone, as we have to plug in manual data. Having said that, thanks for the input. This is a viable approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name using this environment variable (it's not exactly the function name, but it's the name of the site under which the function app is running):

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%")
```